# How to use AJAX to call Rails Create action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, youtube-api

I'm using the Youtube UploadWidget API and I would like to send data Youtube returns to the create action in the controller. I am currently doing this, but it's not working

```
$.get('/posts/create?param1=blah&param2=blahblah')
```

In the console, the url looks right, but instead of calling create it is calling show instead

```
Started GET "/posts/create?title=dsd&video=true&content=32OwWeyqXsc&event=[object%20Object]" for 128.12.174.98 at 2013-03-25 07:48:06 +0000
```

Processing by PostsController#show as */*

What should I be doing to make this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the POST http-verb. Look at [rails routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

```
$.post('/posts?param1=blah&param2=blahblah')
```

I don't know if this works as written since the above code has no callback: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
Also note that the "create" is not part of the url.

I would recommend using a form like this, which i used in my project:

```
paramObj = {param1: "blah", param2: "blahblah"};
callback = function(data){/*...*/};
url = "/posts";
$.post(url,paramObj,callback);
```